# Angularjs unit testing and httpbackend timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I m not new in test world as I worked for many times in TDD using mocha sinon chai and nodejs.

I m actually a bit disturbed with Angularjs testing and the way it works.

Actually, I need to test the simplest method I can do with this :

```
/** @test {HateoasService#loadRessource}*/
describe('HateoasService', function() {

  let service = null;
  let remoteBackend = null;
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

  beforeEach(inject((HateoasService, $httpBackend) => {
    remoteBackend = $httpBackend;
    service = HateoasService;
  }));

  afterEach(function() {
    remoteBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    remoteBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  it('should be resolved a promise with status 200', () => {

    remoteBackend.when('GET', 'http://google.fr')
      .respond(200, {});

    service.loadRessource('http://google.fr').then((res) => {
      expect(res.status).toEqual(200);
      remoteBackend.flush();
    });
  });

});
```

That should cover this code :

```
loadRessource(ressource) {
    return this.http.get(ressource);
  }
```

However, it seems that I m missing something since I m having a trouble with httBackend flushing :  Error: Unflushed requests: 1.

Can you help me make this test working ?

Answer (score 1):

The function that is the second argument to `it` needs a parameter to tell mocha its asynchronous. After flushing, invoke the callback.

```
it('should be resolved a promise with status 200', done => {

remoteBackend.when('GET', 'http://google.fr')
  .respond(200, {});

service.loadRessource('http://google.fr').then((res) => {
  expect(res.status).toEqual(200);
  remoteBackend.flush();
  done();
});
```

});